# Typescript Generic class and Object.assign cannot see the value

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and typing overall. I am using the generics for dynamic properties. This is not my actual code, but I am facing the same issue.

```
class Units<T> {
    constructor(units: T) {
        Object.assign(this, units);
    }
}

const myUnits = {
    archers: 5,
    samurais: 10,
    berserks: 3
};

const army = new Units(myUnits);

army.archers;
```

Error on the last line.

```
Property 'archers' does not exist on type 'Units<{ archers: number; samurais: number; berserks: number; }>'.
```

What am I doing wrong, maybe there is better approach? If I can do that on JS why Typescript restricting?

Comment: Well, `Units<T>` means that you will have a `Units` instance that uses that generic `T` you pass into the constructor. It does not mean that `Units` will inherit any properties off `T`. Think of it like this - you have, say a `Person` class which has a `name` property, but `Array<Person>` *doesn't* have `name` property - it doesn't inherit anything from the generic it uses.

Comment: @VLAZ But how then union so all `T` properties will be in `Units` too?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I'm not that used to TS personally, I'm more familiar with types from Java and what you describe is an extremely unusual case for Java - having a class `A<T>` where `T` determines what fields and methods instances of `A` have is simply put strange. This sort of situation is typically more suited to composition, if anything. I suppose there is some TypeScript way to say that a method that does something to the effect of `<t> method(T arg): ? extends T` but it's still odd. Perhaps you should look at mixins as that's effectively what you do, rather than a generic class.

Answer (score 1):

I think using classes is overkill for what you're trying to achieve in your example.
If you're trying to create a mechanism for creating new object which have the same fields as those passed into it, you can simply create a new object my spreading your initial value:

```
const myUnits = {
    archers: 5,
    samurais: 10,
    berserks: 3
};


const army = {...myUnits};

alert(army.archers);
```

And to answer your question about why Typescript restricts you, this is the beauty of Typescript, it prevents you from changing the shapes and values of your types in unexpected ways. The way your class is defined it doesn't hold any of the properties  that `myUnits` holds.

If you really wish to go with a class based approach, (and i'd suggest sticking to a more functional approach) you could do something like the following:

```
class Units<T> {
    archers: number=0
    samurais: number=0
    berserks:number =0
    constructor(units: T) {
        Object.assign(this, units);
    }
}

const myUnits = {
    archers: 5,
    samurais: 10,
    berserks: 3
};


const army = new Units(myUnits);

army.archers;
army.samurais;
army.berserks;

army.a; //disallowed
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that works with the class approach is to use a public property. For example, `units` will be assigned and typed properly. The only caveat is this will now be used as `army.units.archers`.

```js
class Units<T> {
  public units: T;

  constructor(units: T) {
    this.units = units;
  }
}

const myUnits = {
  archers: 5,
  samurais: 10,
  berserks: 3
};

const army = new Units(myUnits);

army.units.archers;
```

However, if you don't *need* a class based approach, using a function could also work:

```js
const Units2 = <T>(units: T): T => {
  return units;
};

const army2 = Units2(myUnits)

army2.archers;
```

Finally, if you only need a shallow copy, you could use spread syntax:

```js
const army3 = { ...myUnits }

army3.archers;
```

All of these are typed properly. See them in the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEGEBsEMGdYFAIMY3qAqgOwJYBdYAeAFQD5QBvBUUABwFcAjSHZUe3AgLlGIG4kNZAHsssPACd6yPMIkAKDvlg9iASkrUaoPAAscsAHRKCoALztOsATQC+CeylHjQAWwCe2Zec01oE5F0AUwkVUABWABotWGhXegloAx4ARgAGaJpGENgQgGswgGYHAScxPFB-Dx8sIIB3TCt5Dy8CNVKq92MrQ39AnNKQUAAxDhkcUUraWglhaECkEXLG5QAmHxJSRStVNVVzcioaCSC8BKxLZQFbUqWXTvWLVthV5s8rNSQH3oDg0MGwABlGZBaAAE0WzgqnUKPgooEMiJaVlAjhhP36-yAA)